# Centroid of a plane figure of a plane figure.

Tags: centroid

A plane figure is enclosed by the parabola $y^2 =4x$ and the line $y=2x$. Determine the position of the centroid of the figure.

Here is what I tried :
Plotted the graph. 
$y=4ax, y=2x \\
4x(x-1)=0 \quad x=1, x=0\\$

$\bar{x}=\frac{\int xy \mathrm{dx} }{\int y\mathrm{ dx} }$=

$\frac {\int ^1_0 x^{\frac{3} {2 }} } {\int^1_0 x^{\frac{1 } {2 }} }\mathrm{dx} $=

$\frac{ \frac{2} {5} x^{\frac{5 } {2 } }} {\frac{2} {3}x^{\frac{3 }{2 } }}$ $\Biggr|^1_0$=$0.6$

etc

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: You are using $y$ in the integrand. But which $y$... ?

Comment: The one that defined the parabola

Comment: Why do you neglect the other ?

Comment: Well, I felt I needed the other only to get the limits of the integral

Comment: Think that the lower curve could change without changing the integration limits. (E.g. $y=2x^2$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\overline x=\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^1 x(\sqrt{4x}-2x)\,dx}{\displaystyle\int_0^1 (\sqrt{4x}-2x)\,dx}.$$

Comment: Oh. I see. Thank you